# How to set height of a SWT ToolItem?

Tags: java, height, swt, toolbar

Having a ToolItem with a 32x32 image and a text caption, the image is displayed far too small. Is it possible to set the height of a SWT ToolItem programatically?

I am not asking for a solution using CoolItem.

Increasing the size of the parent ToolBar and (parent of parent) Composite did not help. The ToolBar becomes heigher, but the ToolItem height seems fixed.

Comment: The ToolItem normally shows the image full size. How are you creating the image and ToolItem?

Comment: Problem solved, images are adjusted to the size of the first image added into a ToolBar.

Comment: @user1438038 Please consider posting your solution as an answer.

Comment: Done. Sorry, did not see that button. It just said 'Add comment', so I assumed I cannot answer my own Q.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution:**

It is not possible to resize ToolItems manually. **All images in a ToolBar are scaled automatically to match the size of the FIRST image added to the ToolBar.** In my case the first ToolItem had a very small image and was disposed early on, that is why subsequent ToolItems were smaller than expected.

Comment: Please note, however, that this rule is true on Windows (maybe on Linux) but not on MacOS X: in the latter case, the first image will set the **height** of the Toolbar, but not the width of the subsequent ToolItems (which can, then, be larger). Moreover, their images are vertically cropped (if they are larger) or centered (if they are smaller), but not scaled.